# How to make /proc-like files

Tags: linux

I want to make a service, that runs like a daemon. It runs in the background and downloads things here and there.

It isn't much that I want to present to the user, just some statistics of docs downloaded in the day/week and how many errors occurred, etc...

So I wanted to make just a "virtual file" where the information is displayed. Like the files in GNU/Linux in the `/proc` directory.

My question is: what is the convention to do this? Where can I put this file (`/proc` is just for the linux kernel stats). Can I somehow create a "virtual file" (like a socket or so) or is it better to write a real file? Or is this idea stupid?

Comment: Why would you want to save this information in a _/proc like_ file? you know it would take up RAM..
I would have done it with systemd service, and write its log to a file in /var/log/<your service>

Comment: i have the same opinion of making it as systemd service

Comment: IMHO a `/proc` file is more elegant. you do just `cat /proc/myservice` and you see a "dashboard" of useful information. Meanwhile reading the log is a nightmare.